# snappy ubuntu core install basic packages

Tags: ubuntu-core

How to install basic package on snappy Ubuntu core, like nano git wget etc.

I tried the `dpkg -i ***.deb` ,but there are also need some dependent packages

Answer (score 2):

The workaround posted by Lin is fine on 15.04 but in 16.04 LTS you will have a different mechanism, called the 'classic dimension', that will give you a traditional deb based filesystem alongside the snappy filesystems. That way you can use git or other tools on a snappy system and pop back and forth between the snappy and classic dimensions.

Comment: what are the mount points of the classic and snap filesystems in each others 'dimensions'?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no such snap available (search it with `snappy search NAME`), you will need to install it with the .deb package. And you will need to install all the other necessary packages as well.

For example, if you want to install git on it, you will need these packages:

```
git-man (>> 1:2.1.4)
git-man (<< 1:2.1.4-.)
libc6 (>= 2.16)
libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2)
liberror-perl
libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1)
libpcre3
perl-modules
zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0)
```

(liberror-perl depends on [perl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/amd64/perl/5.20.2-2), you will need that as well)

You can find the dependency from the "Package relationship" section of [git project page on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/amd64/git/1:2.1.4-2.1), just download all these .deb packages and put them on your system:

```
(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~/git$ ls
git-man_2.1.4-2.1_all.deb                    liberror-perl_0.17-1.1_all.deb        perl_5.20.2-2_amd64.deb
git_2.1.4-2.1_amd64.deb                      libexpat1_2.1.0-6ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libc6_2.21-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb                libpcre3_8.35-3.3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
libcurl3-gnutls_7.38.0-3ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  perl-modules_5.20.2-2_all.deb
```

And install them on your snappy Ubuntu Core:

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /; sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

That's it!

```
(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~/git$ git --version
git version 2.1.4
```

Comment: `sudo mount -o remount,rw /; sudo dpkg -i *.deb` potentially breaks the system.

Comment: @sergiusens you mean the remount part or the installation part? Maybe I should add another line for reminding people to remount it back to read-only with `sudo mount -o remount,ro /`